# Execute JS function from Code behind (with Parameter)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm working on some Code which loads the a page and selects the required nav tab. This works great in the .aspx file, but I don't know how to trigger with the code behind.

Here is the element that I would like to select

```
<li class="nav-item" runat="server">                    
  <a  class="nav-link" id="pills-request-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-request" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-request" aria-selected="false" onclick="OnTabChange(this)">Request</a>
</li>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var tabName = $("#TabName").val() != "" ? $("#TabName").val() : "pills-home";
    $('.tab-content div').removeClass('active').removeClass('show');
    $('#' + tabName + '-tab').addClass('active');
    $('#' + tabName).addClass(' show active');
    if ($("#TabName").val() != "" && $("#TabName").val() != "1") {
        ("#pills-user-tab").addClass(' admin');
        ("#pills-holiday-tab").addClass(' admin');
        ("#pills-add-tab").addClass(' admin');
    }
});
function OnTabChange(currentTab) {
    if (currentTab != null)
        console.log(currentTab);
        $("#TabName").val(currentTab.id.replace('-tab', ''));
}
```

Code behind

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pills-request-tab", OnTabChange(this), true);
```

I know that the parameter in Code behind is not OnTabChange(this). I would like to know how I can pass the object from code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution look like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pills-request-tab", "OnTabChange(<a  class='nav-link' id='pills-request-tab' data-toggle='pill' href ='#pills-request' role ='tab' aria-controls='pills-request' aria-selected='false' onclick ='OnTabChange(this)' > Request</a>)", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply call the `OnTabChange` like this. Only `this` will not work. You will need to pass a string.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pills-request-tab", "OnTabChange('tabID')", true);
```